# Can't use Material UI in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I tried everything in the past 4 hours.
My problem is that I want to display a form like a table. I am trying to do it with `material ui`. But after I installed material ui, and some other packages I got an error when I try to compile my code:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolvenode_modules\@babel\runtime/helpers/esm/classCallCheck"
```

I also tried `npm install  @babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55`, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: please provide more information about your tech stack. Even better a sandbox showing the described behaviour

Comment: react -v
6.4.1
material ui -v
6.4.1
@babel\runtime -v
6.4.1